# ANOVA Table Dots Meaning

Tags: anova

First of all i want to say that maybe my question is already answered but i am really new in ANOVA table and i can't really understand 100% the answers. My question is if someone can explain me what the dots mean (single dot, double dot, tripple dot) and when the double dot is acceptable.

[image]

Comment: This looks like it is an assignment and you are required to fill in the dots.  If it is output from a program, it is bizarre. Please provide details.

Comment: I am sorry, this is everything i have it's an exercise from a book, which doesn't give the solution

Comment: What does the exercise say besides giving this table?

Comment: One more thing, to calculate the dots, nothing more. I can calculate the dots of course .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The single asterisk on the regression row, Ms column is $\frac{SSR}{DF}=\frac{135.6}{4} = 33.9$

The one on the error row, df column is $19 - 4=15$
The triple asterisk on the error row, Ms column is $\frac{SSE}{DF} = \frac{124.2}{15}=8.28$
The double asterisk on the regression row, $F_o$ column is $\frac{MSR}{MSE}=4.09$
The SS for total is $135.6+124.2=259.8$
FYI it was an assignment

Comment: I know how to calculate them but it's the only thing that these  exercise wants? I mean , the  exercise wants you to explain what are the three dots. So the only thing i have do to it's to find them?

Comment: Yes. All you have to do is find them, it seems.